# Wasted space in layout in CPP Core Guidelines

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines

I was reading **CPP Core Guidelines**, [P.9: Don’t waste time or space](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#p9-dont-waste-time-or-space):

**Example, Bad:**

```
struct X {
    char ch;
    int i;
    string s;
    char ch2;

    X& operator=(const X& a);
    X(const X&);
};
```

Then it states:

> ... ***Note that the layout of X guarantees that at least 6 bytes (and most likely more) are wasted.***

Why 6 bytes are guaranteed to be wasted? And how could be fixed (except the constructor declaration whom are source of waste of the example)

Comment: The bytes are wasted because of padding after each `char` member to align everything at 4 bytes.

Comment: Have you already seen this?: [Wikipedia: Data structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Comment: Interesting read: The Lost Art of Structure Packing  http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struct starts with a default alignment. The first member `ch` is aligned. `i` is an `int` and that must be four byte aligned (when `int` is four bytes long), so between `ch` and `i` you get three bytes padding. The same is true at the end of the struct after `ch2` where you get three bytes of padding. These are inserted so that for a `X x[2];` both elements are correctly aligned in memory.

```
struct X {
    char ch;
    char padding1[3]; // so that int i is int-aligned (four bytes)
    int i;
    string s;
    char ch2;
    char padding2[3]; // end of struct must also be aligned
};
```